# 'C:\Users\User' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, remote-access, remote-server

When I using VS code remote SSH connection, it always fails to connect and warning me "'C:\Users\User' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I guess the issue is the path "C:\Users\User" contains space, and the full path should be something like "C:\Users\User Name...", but I don't know how to suppress and add the escape character to space.

Can anyone help me to resolve the problem? Many thanks!

Other information:

Operating system: Windows 10.

I have installed OpenSSH and I can connect to the remote server using windows PowerShell or git bash.

The version for VS code is 1.43.0 and extension is 0.50.0.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, so it must be a recent bug.

Comment: I am also having this problem after upgrading to 1.43 (sigh, I forgot I should never upgrade working Microsoft stuff unless I have a good reason). I tried the connection with log level DEBUG3, and got no extra information about what it was trying to do after it found the server host key.

Comment: I solved this problem by opening the Remote SSH settings and specifying the path to ssh on my remote machine in Remote SSH:Path and deselecting Remote SSH: Use local server.

Comment: Wrap the path in single quotes `'<path to wrap>'`